# How can I make Haskell ghci show error messages

Tags: haskell, ghci

Haskell ghci doesn't show error messages, just "error: " without any message.  I've looked through documentation and searched the web, but no joy.  What am I missing?

I'm running on Windows 10 with Ghci 8.10.7 (but I had the same problem with a version I was using a couple of years ago).

So that this question might be helpful to someone in the future, I added the following in response to the comments:

I've been having that problem since I first tried Haskell a couple of years ago.  Since I didn't use Haskell much (I'm a Scala programmer), I just lived with it.  But then I decided to try to fix it -

1.) I uninstalled Haskell Platform and Haskell Stack using Windows Uninstall

2.) rebooted

3.) Installed Haskell using GHCup from https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/, pasting the long command string on that page into WPS and then accepting all defaults

4.) rebooted

5.) started Windows Command Prompt terminal

6.) started ghci in the terminal

7.) at the Prelude> prompt I typed "something bad" (without the quotes).  (later - I got the same result with any other entry that causes a compile error.)

ghci responded:

```
        error:          (in red)
```

and another Prelude> prompt

Comment: Please give an example of what you're doing. It's also worth mentioning where you're seeing terminal output. Conhost? An IDE window?

Comment: GHCi shows detailed error messages by default. If it's not showing them to you, it's because you changed something in a way that broke it. Please explain exactly what you did.

Comment: It's also completely unclear whether you are talking about compiler errors, or runtime errors. If you've put an `error ""` in your code somewhere then you'll certainly just get `error:` (or similar) if that gets evaluated, but that would be your own fault.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I thought that at first too, but even then you get a stacktrace.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sorry I wasn't clear.  I wanted my question to be concise.  But I haven't used Haskell much - and since GHCI prints "error: " for compile errors but apparently reports an exception and maybe a stack trace for run-time errors, I thought I'd included enough to be clear to people who knew Haskell.  Anyway - it's compile errors I was talking about.

Comment: @Joseph I edited the question to add more detail about what I did.  Is that enough for you to tell what I changed that broke ghci?  Pleas let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: What happens when you select/copy the text where the error should be? Is the text not printed, or converted to blanks, or printed in the same colour as the background?

Comment: @Jon Purdy - Good call Jon. I selected and copied the area where the text should have been. I was able to paste the error into an editor or into the window where ghci was running. Apparently ghci doesn't work well with black on white terminal windows

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments, I found two solutions - or rather two work-arounds:

1. I found that ghci shows (compiler) errors just fine running in Windows Power Shell.
2. Apparently ghci doesn't work well with the color settings in Windows Command Prompt.  I prefer black text on white background.  The problem goes away when the colors are set to white text on black background.

Thanks to Carl and Jon Purdy.  Your comments solved the problem.